# Error Changing Pivot Table Data Source using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm changing the data source of pivot table in excel using vba. I have this code below but it's returning a Type mismatch error at this line: 
    Set pvtcache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, 
    SourceData:=DataRange)

Here's my script which I also got from various solutions in google and stackoverflow.

```
Dim Data_sht As Worksheet
Dim Pivot_sht As Worksheet
Dim StartPoint As Range``
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim PivotName As String
Dim NewRange As String
Dim pvtcache As PivotCache


Set Data_sht = wb.Sheets("FINAL_DATA")
Set Pivot_sht = wb.Worksheets("Summary")

PivotName = "PivotTable1"

'Dynamically Retrieve Range Address of Data
 Set StartPoint = Data_sht.Range("A1")
 Set DataRange = Data_sht.Range(StartPoint, 
 StartPoint.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))

NewRange = Data_sht.Name & "!" & _
DataRange.Address(RowAbsolute:=True, ColumnAbsolute:=True, 
ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, External:=True)

'Change Pivot Table Data Source Range Address

Set pvtcache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, 
SourceData:=DataRange)
With Pivot_sht
    .PivotTables(PivotName).ChangePivotCache pvtcache
 End With

'Refresh Pivot Table
Pivot_sht.PivotTables(PivotName).RefreshTable

'Message
 MsgBox PivotName & "'s data source range has been successfully updated!"
```

Comment: Look at http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot11.html#newcache

Answer (score 0):

Only these lines will successfully create and change the Pivot Cache....

```
Set pvtcache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, Data_sht.Name & "!" & Data_sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address)
Pivot_sht.PivotTables(1).ChangePivotCache pvtcache
```